# Как поместить значение нового ключа JSON в условие?

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api, if

```
import vk_api
from config import mytoken

session = vk_api.VkApi(token=mytoken)
vk = session.get_api()

friends = session.method("friends.get", {'user_id': *id пользователя*})
for i in friends['items']:
    friend_info = session.method('users.get', {'user_ids': i})
    if friend_info[0]['deactivated'] == 'deleted':
        continue
    else:
        print(friend_info)
```

При запросе информации о НЕудаленном пользователе с помощью `users.get` мне возвращает JSON:

```
[{'first_name': 'Вадим', 'id': *id пользователя*, 'last_name': 'Журавлев', 'can_access_closed': True, 'is_closed': False}]
```

А при запросе информации об удаленном пользователе появляется новый ключ `deactivated`:

```
[{'first_name': 'Lieben', 'id': *id пользователя*, 'last_name': 'Spruke', 'deactivated': 'deleted'}]
```

Но цикл с пропуском не работает:

```
if friend_info[0]['deactivated'] == 'deleted':
            continue
```

Так как, при сканировании друзей с неудаленными страницами возвращается JSON файл без ключа 'deactivated', на что в последствии предъявляется жалоба:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Стас\Desktop\python\strbot\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    if friend_info[0]['deactivated'] == 'deleted':
KeyError: 'deactivated'
```

Задача: программа должна пропускать друзей, у которых в JSON появляется новый ключ 'deactivated'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `dict.get()`, который по умолчанию возвращает `None` если ключ не найден:

```
if friend_info[0].get('deactivated') == 'deleted':
    continue
```

В итоге вы получите короткую и понятную запись.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать проверку на наличие ключа 'deactivated'.

```
if 'deactivated' in friend_info[0] and friend_info[0]['deactivated'] == 'deleted':
    continue
else:
...
```